# It seems to me that [fabric] tag is missused for Fabric.io

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

These are the 3 latest questions in the [fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric) tag (07/22/2016):

- [Fatal issue in libdvm.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517947/fatal-issue-in-libdvm-so)
- [Uploading .dSYM on Fabric (crashlytics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502103/uploading-dsym-on-fabric-crashlytics)
- [Crashlytics installing - stuck on verifying installation step 2 of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391133/crashlytics-installing-stuck-on-verifying-installation-step-2-of-2)

None of them are related to the Python library [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/), and my attempt to remove the tag has been rejected for the 2nd link.

What about creating a [`fabric-io`](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics) tag so those two different things stop getting mixed up?

Comment: Well at least call it `[fabric-io]` so it doesn't look like `[fabriclo]`.

Comment: Better proposal: [fabric]->[python-fabric]; create [fabric.io]; burn [fabric]

Comment: @CodyGray fixed.

Comment: @Braiam That would be fine

Comment: @Braiam It's the first time I post here, what's going to happends now ? someone is going to review this and if he feel it's right, he'll creats the tags? Should I do something or my job is done?